Depth of field doesn't work in Cycles only when I import external files
I keep running into issues with depth of field in Cycles while working on one of my projects. No matter how much I tweak the camera settings, I always get the same result: either everything is blurred, or everything is in focus :(
When I use depth of field with Blender's default camera and cube preset, it works fine. But when I try to use it in my own files with different products and camera setups, it just stops working... it's always the same story. Adding blur in post-production has become really frustrating.
I’d love it if you could help me out! I want the hanging lamp in the center of the image to be in focus (with the plane called "lamp_focus reference"). I’ve also included a few screenshots for reference.
Please, if anyone could help, I would really appreciate it


Your distance is animated, see the brown/yellow color on the distance field.
That might be overriding the focus object. Delete the keyframes for the distance. If later you need to vary distance during animation, you can use an empty as focus instead and move the empty around.

Hey Daniel, I didn't want to make an animation and I deleted all the frames. But, the problem still remains :(

Is the field still colored? If it is, the frames are still there.

Nono, I deleted all the frames and it returned to the classic grey aspect

The problem of having it totally focused/ totally unfocused still there :(

So, reduce f-stop to a smaller number (Your scene might be too small). If that doesn't work, you can share your file (you may delete everything and leave only the lamp and window if you are worried about copyrights) - instructions for sharing: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

The f-stop value is something I've already worked on, but it doesn't work... is there anyway to upload the file in blend exchange over 30MB? I cleaned it a bit, but it still 280MB...Can I share a wetransfer link?

I guess nothing prevents you from doing that, although not recommended.

No problem...there's no any important copyright file there
https://we.tl/t-wZPM0i86gn

Your camera is 500 meters away....
There is absolutely no chance of getting a depth of field variance that far away!

You can scale everything down (0.01) and things will start to make sense.


Oh, strange...in the image I sent initially it was written like 300cm away. Anyway, it starts working! Thanks a lot :)

Interesting.... could it be a version bug (I use 4.2.0)? Or maybe some system language issue? Did you try to configure it to have "cm" as standard units?

Yes, usually I go to units, change it in 0.01 and change it in cm...it's bit strange. I'll update the version. Thanks again ;)

@RobertoGurnari Well, somehow the Unit Scale is back to 1 instead of 0.01 - but there is the problem, the Unit Scale. If you change the scale of Blender's scene units, it is as if you build a scale model - and your camera is then a tiny model as well, with everything like its virtual lens etc. scaled down, too. So when something is 300 cm away from the camera, to the camera this is 300 m and therefore you have the depth of field problems which Daniel describes. If you want to model in real world dimensions, better leave the Unit Scale at 1 and scale the objects to match the dimensions.
